# wix: unable to detect servicepacks

Tags: wix, nant

I am trying to detect .net framework 2.0 service pack 2. But it seems that wix is unable to detect that.
below is the script that i am using.

```
NAnt:
<exec program="${wix.dir}\light.exe" workingdir=".\wix" commandline="-ext WixUIExtension -ext WixNetFxExtension -cultures:en-us SampleFirst.wixobj -out ${release.dir}\NantTest.msi"/> 

wix:
<PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK20"/>
<Condition Message="This application requires .NET Framework 3.5 SP1. Please install the .NET Framework then run this installer again.">
    <![CDATA[Installed OR (NETFRAMEWORK20_SP_LEVEL and NOT NETFRAMEWORK20_SP_LEVEL = "#2")]]>
</Condition>
```

It is able to detect  the ,net framework. But it is not detecting service packs. Any suggestion?

Comment: it is able to detect. I had mentioned the wrong property. :)

Comment: I find the question not clear at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use

```
<PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK20_SP_LEVEL"/>
```

instead of

```
<PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK20"/>
```